# Failed to create javascript array inside another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here's my code:

```
var Constants = {
    strings = {
        FIRST: 'First Value',
        SECOND: 'Second Value',
        THIRD: 'Third Value',
    },
    numbers = {
        FIRST: 1,
        SECOND: 2,
        THIRD: 3,
    }
};
```

And this how I need to call the array:

```
Constants.strings.FIRST
Constants.numbers.FIRST
```

But I got this error: "SyntaxError: missing: after property id"

Comment: swap your `=` signs for `:`

Comment: also, they're not arrays - they're objects. See https://dev.to/zac_heisey/objects-vs-arrays-2g0e

Comment: you used = instead of a colon (:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is actually not an array, it is a nested [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics) of objects**. So **each nested object have a pair of key and value**.

let's say we got `strings` as key and

```js
{
  FIRST: 'First Value',
  SECOND: 'Second Value',
  THIRD: 'Third Value',
}
```

as value *(in this particular case, the value itself is an object too)*, so **each key and value have to be separated by a colon**.

Then, each pair should look like the below example instead of provided one:

```js
strings: {
  FIRST: 'First Value',
  SECOND: 'Second Value',
  THIRD: 'Third Value',
}
```

You are getting an error in this case because **you used `=` instead of a colon (`:`)** and it won't be recognized as an object.

So your final object should be something like this:

```js
var Constants = {
    strings: {
        FIRST: 'First Value',
        SECOND: 'Second Value',
        THIRD: 'Third Value',
    },
    numbers: {
        FIRST: 1,
        SECOND: 2,
        THIRD: 3,
    }
};

console.log(Constants.strings.FIRST)
console.log(Constants.numbers.FIRST)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this

```
var Constants = {
    strings : {
        FIRST: 'First Value',
        SECOND: 'Second Value',
        THIRD: 'Third Value',
    },
    numbers : {
        FIRST: 1,
        SECOND: 2,
        THIRD: 3,
    }
};
```